# Modifying the counter in a for-loop

Tags: for-loop, iteration, julia

I was surprised by this behavior (in Julia)

```
for i in 1:10
  println(i)
  i=i+4
end
```

prints:

```
1
2
...
9
10
```

(modification of `i` in the loop body is not taken into account)

In C/C++

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
  std::cout << "\n" << i;
  i+=4;
}
```

you would get:

```
1
6
```

Reading [Julia doc:iteration](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/#lib-collections-iteration-1), I realized that the **for loop**

```
for i = I   # or  "for i in I"
    # body
end
```

is certainly transformed into:

```
state = start(I)
while !done(I, state)
    (i, state) = next(I, state)
    # body
end
```

In that case we understand that `i` modifications are not taken into account. Everything depends on the **state** variable.

**Question1:** am I right with this explanation?

**Question2:** the **state** variable seems to be inaccessible/hidden to the user. By consequence, construction like

```
for i in 1:10
  println(i)
  i=i+4
end
```

with a **for loop** seems impossible. Is it correct?

(I know that I can use a `while i<=n` loop)

Comment: You might find the alternative explanation at: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/variables-and-scoping/#For-Loops-and-Comprehensions-1 helpful — it describes it in terms of behavior instead of implementation.

Comment: @MattB. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: yes, and it is in fact the same as in python:

```
for i in range(10):
   print(i)
   i=i+4
```

Outputs 0,1,2,...9.

Several concepts in julia's have been influenced by python.
Here is an explanation of python iterator:

- [What exactly are Python's iterator, iterable, and iteration protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)
- http://www.diveintopython3.net/iterators.html#a-fibonacci-iterator

Julia's `start`, `next`, `done` are equivalent to Pythons `__iter__` method, `next` and raising the `StopIteration` exception.

**Question 2**: The variable state is indeed not accessible if a loop is start with `for i in 1:3`.

Comment: It might be worth adding an example of how to do the above with `while` loop just for future reference?